# How do I start the Merryweather heist?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Trevor mentioned doing some flight training before starting the heist, which I did, but I haven't received word from Trevor about starting the mission. I read online that Michael's flight training and Franklin's shooting range training are optional, but I still have no indication on how to start the heist on my map. (The only marked missions are Lester's, which I'm leaving for later.) Is this bugged?

Comment: Did you already steal the helicopter and sub (depending on your approach)?

Comment: I had the same "problem" - afaik you just need to proceed with some other story missions and then at some point you will get call that everything is ready!

Answer (score 1):

Lester's first assassination mission done first will advance your game to the point of progressing, and having him call you.

When I was trying to progress the story, I had done all regular and side missions, but left Lester for last. My game had nothing else to do, so I completed his mission. Immediately afterwords, I got a call allowing me to attempt the heist.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch back to Trevor and wait a while for the helicopter/sub-stealing missions (via cell phones). As I mentioned, there wasn't any other major mission left to do before this.

I don't recall whether I did Lester's first assassination mission before the calls came—I think not, actually.